# Move and Replace Files

Tags: php, windows, server

I need to move files and directories from current directory to another directory. The code below works fine for **files**, but i have two problems:

1 - Directories are not moved ("Not Moved" is showed)

2 - After it fails, if i try to delete the old files and folders (that are not replaced with the new ones), it shows me a Permission error from Windows (that had not occurred before)

Any idea about what's wrong?

```
<?php

//$path is my folder with files
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('..', '.'));


foreach($files as $file){
    $from = $path.'/'.$file;
    $to = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site_root/'.$file;

    if(rename($from, $to)){
        echo "Moved";
    }
    else{
        echo "Not moved";
    }
}


closedir(opendir($path));
rmdir($path);

?>
```

**EDIT**: `rmdir` not works too...

Comment: The permission problem might be related to what the user, that runs the server has access to. Are there any warnings in the server logs?

Comment: I think that the permission error occurs because rename function don't 'release' the folder...  Because of this i put the closedir function...

Comment: Antonio The fact `rmdir` does not work either suggests otherwise. Rename AFAIK does not open file handle, that would need to be closed (if that is what you mean by 'release'). Did you check the logs?